# Python dictionary list with multiple keys

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, so I apologize for any mistakes found within my post. I have recently been playing around with APIs with Python and came across an API that responds to my request with a list of dictionaries for films for the respective studio providing the API (Not sure if it is a JSON list of dictionaries) From the list of dictionaries I am trying to create a for-loop to get rotten tomato scores greater than 90, but I would also like to get the corresponding title of the movie within the for-loop. I have tried adding `if key == 'rt_score' and 'title'`, but I don't know if this is the correct approach and whether it would lead me to the correct solution. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")

print(response.status_code)
json_response = response.json()

for dicti in json_response:
    for key in dicti:
        if key == 'rt_score':
            rt_score = int(dicti[key])
            if rt_score > 90:
                print(str(key) + ': ' + str(rt_score))
```

This is what the JSON list of dictionaries looks like:

```js
[
   {
      "description": "The orphan Sheeta inherited a mysterious crystal that links her to the mythical sky-kingdom of Laputa. With the help of resourceful Pazu and a rollicking band of sky pirates, she makes her way to the ruins of the once-great civilization. Sheeta and Pazu must outwit the evil Muska, who plans to use Laputa's science to make himself ruler of the world.",
      "director": "Hayao Miyazaki",
      "id": "2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe",
      "locations": [
         "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/locations/"
      ],
      "people": [
         "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/"
      ],
      "producer": "Isao Takahata",
      "release_date": "1986",
      "rt_score": "95",
      "species": [
         "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/species/af3910a6-429f-4c74-9ad5-dfe1c4aa04f2"
      ],
      "title": "Castle in the Sky",
      "url": "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe",
      "vehicles": [
         "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/vehicles/"
      ]
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the title within your for-loop by `dicti['title']`.

Full example using your code:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")

print(response.status_code)
json_response = response.json()

for dicti in json_response:
    for key in dicti:
        if key == 'rt_score':
            rt_score = int(dicti[key])
            if rt_score > 90:
                print(dicti['title'] + ' - ' str(key) + ': ' + str(rt_score))
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over the keys you need to call `.keys()` on the dictionary, but you do not need to do that. Just use the key with the dictionary like shown below.

```
for dict_ in json_response:
    if float(dict_['rt_score']) > 90:
        title = dict_['title']
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
for film in json_response:
    if int(film['rt_score']) > 90:
        print(f"{film['title']}: {film['rt_score']}")
```

This uses a f-string for printing, so needs at least Python 3.6.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not yet proficient with f-strings, but this was also a solution that helped with my issue and will consider using in the future!